# Is it Possible to add the class(in diff Module) to classpath and use it with Reflection

Tags: java, scala, maven

I am working on multi-module project in scala, where I need to call the method present in different module, different class but because of cyclic build dependency between the modules, cannot directly add dependency to maven and use it.
As a work around is it possible to add the class to class path and using [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) scan the classpath call the method and use it.

```
Project 
 |__Module A 
 |__Module B
```

PS. This is sample scenario, which I am kind of doing POC on the possibility, I am aware there are other ways to remove cyclic dependencies.

Comment: Eliminate the cyclic dependency. This is a real problem. You get rid of this first...